# List index out of range when solving a Kattis Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I am working with this problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/whowantstoliveforever). And I am getting list index out of range because of `_list[index-1] == "0"` and `_list[index+1] == "0"` and it clearly does not exist. I am wondering if there is a better way to go with this problem.

below is my code.

```
import sys


def liveForever(input_list):
    if len(set(input_list)) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    return False


def print_result(boolean):
    print("LIVE" if boolean else "DIES")


num_cases = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
for i in range(num_cases):
    _list = []
    case = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    for char in case:
        _list.append(char)
    for index in range(len(_list)):
        if (_list[index-1] == "0" and _list[index+1] == "0") or (_list[index-1] == "1" and _list[index+1] == "1"):
            _list[index] == "0"
        elif(_list[index-1] == "0" and _list[index+1] == "1") or (_list[index-1] == "1" and _list[index+1] == "0"):
            _list[index] == "1"
        print(_list)
    print_result(liveForever(_list))
```

Here essentially my output needs to be either LIVES or DIES based on the list.

Comment: What's going to happen when you access `_list[index+1]` in the last iteration of the loop?

Comment: did you try to put   `for index in range(len(_list)-1):`, i guess it might do the trick

Comment: @DeepSpace it's supposed to assume that the empty out of range list element as 0,  its the same for _list[index(0) - 1]

Comment: It's the `+1` that's giving you the issue. Index `-1` is valid in Python. It gets the last element of the list, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase an old doctor joke, if something makes your program crash, [then don't do that.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/Don-t-do-that-then-.html)

[The assignment](https://open.kattis.com/problems/whowantstoliveforever) clearly specifies that the value of any bit outside the valid range is assumed to be zero.  So, before accessing the list, just check if the index is out bounds and return zero if it is.  One way to do that would be using a wrapper function, e.g.:

```
def get_bit(bits, i):
    if 0 <= i < len(bits):
        return bits[i]
    else:
        return 0
```

There are other, possibly more efficient ways to achieve the same result, but I'll leave optimizing the code as the exercise it's supposed to be.

Ps. Note that your code also has (at least) one other bug: you're modifying the list of bits as you're iterating over it.  Since the states of the bits on the next time step is supposed to depend on the states of those bits and their neighbors on the previous step, *before* they're updated, that will give incorrect results.  To make it work, you'll need to have two lists, so that you can store the updated values in one while reading the old values from the other.